# Looping through database for populating listview

Tags: android, database

I am trying to populate listview from the database. The database has three columns row_id, lat and lon. So I have written two methods

```
public String getLat(long l){
.....
}
public String getLon(long l){
.....
}
```

Now in another FragmentAcivity I want to load the listview by getting the name and number for each row_id. So how can I loop through all the row_id in another activity.

I have tried this. This is to load the row_id one by one

```
info.open();
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getAllData();
    String finalR[] = info.returnRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < finalR.length; i++) {
        long m = Long.parseLong(finalR[i]);
        String flat = info.getLat(m);
        String flon = info.getLon(m);
        Log.i(flat, flon);
    }
    info.close();
```

This is returnRows()

```
public String[] returnRows() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_LAT, KEY_LON };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String x[] = new String[10000];
    int iROW = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int i = 0;
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        x[i] = c.getString(iROW);
        i++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

But it is giving me numberformatexception invalid long "null". Please help.

Comment: You should have a separate file/class for your database and a separate class for each table. Then you can call the corresponding methods from any activity....

Comment: I have a seperate class for database

Comment: This line might be a cause of the number format exception : 
long m = Long.parseLong(finalR[i]);

Try logging the values of finalR[i]

Comment: Okak after trying it various times what I finally got is that it is printing the log message of flat and flon and then it is giving me the same exception.

Comment: I will upload the logcat.

Comment: Please check my result. I would love to know why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got finally why it was giving me the exception. In the above code I have

```
 String x[] = new String[10000];
```

But the database didnt contain that many values. I knew the database had only two values so I changed it to 2 and the exception was gone. So it seems that instead of stopping when it encounters a null value it keeps going hence generating the exception.

Comment: You should use `cursor.getCount()` so it will be the correct size every time. You could also avoid looping through the cursor and just use a CursorAdapter, or your own adapter that is backed by a Cursor.